# JupyterHub with SystemUserSpawner fails

Tags: jupyterhub

I'm trying to run a JupyterHub on a virtual machine, using the `dockerspawner.SystemUserSpawner`, spawning Jupyter Lab instances.

My jupyterhub_config.py has the following (extra) lines:

```
c.Spawner.default_url = '/lab'
c.Spawner.cmd = ['jupyter', 'labhub']
c.JupyterHub.spawner_class = 'dockerspawner.SystemUserSpawner'
```

(plus lines for the `bind_url` and `hub_ip`). Everything else should be the default.

Upon running (`jupyterhub -f /etc/jupyterhub/jupyterhub_config.py`) and logging in in the browser, I run into a 500 error. The log on the command line looks as follows:

```
[D 2019-02-26 16:55:37.869 JupyterHub dockerspawner:644] Getting container 'jupyter-testuser'
[D 2019-02-26 16:55:37.873 JupyterHub dockerspawner:629] Container 8bf627d status: {'Dead': False,
     'Error': '',
     'ExitCode': 1,
     'FinishedAt': '2019-02-26T15:55:29.518823812Z',
     'OOMKilled': False,
     'Paused': False,
     'Pid': 0,
     'Restarting': False,
     'Running': False,
     'StartedAt': '2019-02-26T15:55:28.446881243Z',
     'Status': 'exited'}
[W 2019-02-26 16:55:37.874 JupyterHub web:1667] 500 GET /hub/user/testuser/ (www.xxx.yyy.zzz): Spawner failed to start [status=ExitCode=1, Error='', FinishedAt=2019-02-26T15:55:29.518823812Z]. The logs for testuser may contain details.
[D 2019-02-26 16:55:37.875 JupyterHub base:880] No template for 500
```

JupyterHub itself then gets stuck in a (endless?) loop trying to spawn the container every 10 seconds.

Ignoring the missing 500 template, I was little the wiser from the container status message, but `docker logs jupyter-testuser` shows:

```
....
[C 2019-02-26 15:55:29.360 SingleUserLabApp notebookapp:1707] Running as root is not recommended. Use --allow-root to bypass.
[D 2019-02-26 15:55:29.360 SingleUserLabApp application:647] Exiting application: jupyter-notebook
```

When I change `jupyterhub_config.py` to include

```
c.Spawner.cmd = ['jupyter', 'labhub', '--allow-root']
c.DockerSpawner.remove = True
```

things do work, but with an unwanted caveat: I'm now root in the container, and any file I create in the home directory is not owned by `testuser`, but by the (Docker container) `root`. Inside the VM itself, `testuser` can't, for example, delete those files.

(note on `c.DockerSpawner.remove = True`: if I don't include that, JupyterHub gets stuck on the previous container which didn't have `--allow-root`)

The documentation suggests the initial configuration should be correct, and `--allow-root` is not necessary for a standard docker stack (I'm obviously using the default one here, `jupyterhub/singleuser:0.9`).

For comparison, using the `dockerspawner.DockerSpawner` works fine.

I don't see what I'm missing, or where to look for more debugging options. Any suggestions are therefore welcome.

Jupyter(Hub) version 0.9.4 on Ubuntu 18.04.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The mistake is in the `c.Spawner.cmd` (`c.Spawner.cmd = ['jupyter', 'labhub']`).

This starts the Docker container with the arguments `jupyter labhub`, similar to running it from the command line as `docker run jupyter/singleuser:0.9 jupyter labhub` (with some additional environment variables).

Docker will, however, read the first argument after the container name as the `CMD`, not as an argument to the `CMD` in the Dockerfile. That is, the Dockerfile for the base notebook (and thereby the jupyter/singleuser one), has this:

```
# Configure container startup
ENTRYPOINT ["tini", "-g", "--"]
CMD ["start-notebook.sh"]
```

This will run the entrypoint with the command next, i.e. `tini -g -- start-notebook.sh`, followed by arguments given to `docker run`. Since, however, that first argument replaces `CMD`, what is executed is `tini -g -- jupyter`, with `labhub` passed as argument to `jupyter`. The latter bypasses the `start-notebook.sh` and consequently the `start.sh` scripts, which actually take care of handling the user ID settings inside the container. That is, these start scripts prevent root from actually running the jupyter command. Skipping the scripts will not prevent that, and the jupyter command is run as root, with the problems indicated in the question.

There are two possible ways out of this; it's unclear to me which one is the preferred one:

1. include `start-notebook.sh` or `start.sh` in the `c.Spawner.cmd` setting (I've opted directly for `start.sh`):

   ```
   c.Spawner.cmd = ['start.sh', 'jupyter', 'labhub']
   ```

   This will replace the `start-notebook.sh` command with `start.sh` (which is generally fine; the first is a small wrapper around the second), and `jupyter labhub` will then be provided as arguments to `start.sh`. Which is precisely what is needed.
2. set the environment variable `JUPYTER_LAB_ENABLE`, and *disable* the `c.Spawner.cmd`:

   ```
   #c.Spawner.cmd = ['start.sh', 'jupyter', 'labhub']
   c.SystemUserSpawner.environment = {'JUPYTER_ENABLE_LAB': '1'}
   ```

   The `start.sh` looks at the environment variable `JUPYTER_ENABLE_LAB` (which is passed by the `SystemUserSpawner` through to the Docker container), and will run the lab when this variable is set (thus, it doesn't need to be set to `'1'` necessarily). In this case, no extra arguments need to be passed to the Docker container or `start.sh` script, hence `c.Spawner.cmd` is disabled.

Comment: Very thorough! Thanks!